# Textfield does not detect touch

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield, uikeyboard

I found a weird problem in my iOS application written in Swift. Sometimes textfield does not work ie textfield does not detect touch and keyboard is not showing. All the textfields in every viewControllers suddenly stops working. Help is much appreciated thank you.

Edit: Adding some code

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    oldPswdTextField.delegate = self
    newPswdTextField.delegate = self
    confirmPswdTextField.delegate = self
}
```

////On back button click///////

```
func resignAllResponsers()
{
    if oldPswdTextField.isFirstResponder
    {
        oldPswdTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if newPswdTextField.isFirstResponder
    {
        newPswdTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if confirmPswdTextField.isFirstResponder
    {
        confirmPswdTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

/////////////////

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if textField.tag == 0
    {
        showPswdBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeClose.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if textField.tag == 1
    {
        showNewPswdBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeClose.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Seems like other overlay view is added up on your VC at some condition.

Comment: in which scenatio u faced  this, are you checking in simulator or device

Comment: I am checking this in actual device itself. Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)
iOS version 10.3.2

Comment: Everything else on the screen is working.., i can tap button, go back to previous screen etc. But textfield is not detecting any touch let alone calling any textField delegate.

Comment: is text field touch event worked at least once or not. Can u show some of your textfield related code part.

Comment: Textfields are working when the app is running for the first time. But after some screen transitions and push notifications, it stop working. Everything else on the viewController where the textfield is for example buttons are functioning normally.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem was because ui alert controllers were dismissing wrongly. After made it correct, textField problem was sorted out.